# Solving a system of recurrence relations using Mathematica

Tags: numerics, recursion, difference-equations

Can Mathematica solve (for `b[k]` and `c[r]`) the following system of recurrence relations? `b[k]` is defined for only odd natural numbers, and `c[r]` is defined for only even non-negative integers.

For n greater than or equal to 3;

```
b[2n+1] = c[2n] + c[2n-2] + 2*a[n],
c[2n] = b[2n-1] + c[2n-2],
a[n] = .0794367(.460811)^n + .255972(-.675131)^n + .664591(3.21432)^n;

c[0]=1, b[1]=4, c[2]=5, b[3]=10, c[4]=15, b[5]=34.
```

I seemed to have tried "everything" in Mathematica 11, but nothing seems to work.... Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE** (September 4, 2016)

After consolidating everything, here is the question.

Find a "closed-form" solution (formula) to the following piecewise defined recurrence relation:

For integers k greater than or equal to 3:

```
b[k] = b[k-1] + b[k-3] + 2*[.0794367(.460811)^((k-1)/2) + \
.255972(-.675131)^((k-1)/2) + .664591(3.21432)^((k-1)/2)]`
```

If k is odd:

```
b[k] = b[k-1] + b[k-2], if k is even; b[0] = 1, b[1] = 4, b[2] = 5
```

This piecewise defined recurrence relation is the one that I am interested in. I verified (using this piecewise defined recurrence relation, by hand calculations) the correct values:

```
b[0]=1, b[1]=4, b[2]=5, b[3]=10, b[4]=15, b[5]=34, b[6]=49, 
b[7]=108, b[8]=157, b[9]=348, b[10]=505, ...
```

Sincerely,
Richard M. Low

Comment: Have you tried RSolve? What syntax did you use? Many problems are caused by subtle errors in syntax that someone could spot easily.

Comment: please show your efforts, tell us what you've tried. :)

Comment: Please cross reference your posts here with the corresponding ones on Wolfram Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/917888  Just edit your post and include a link (on both websites).  This is to prevent duplication of effort (i.e. two people posting the same answer in two places and not being aware of it).

Answer (score 7):

Eliminating `b` from the first two expressions in the question and redefining `n` yields

```
c[n] == 2 c[n - 1] + c[n - 2] + 2 a[n - 1]
```

Although `RSolve` can handle this expression with `a` as given in the question, it seems better to `Rationalize` it.

```
794367 10^-7 (460811 10^-6)^n+255972 10^-6 (-675131 10^-6)^n+664591 10^-6 (321432 10^-5)^n
```

Then,

```
Simplify[RSolve[{c[n] == 2 c[n - 1] + c[n - 2] + 2 (794367 10^-7 (460811 10^-6)^(n - 1) + 
    255972 10^-6 (-675131 10^-6)^(n - 1) + 664591 10^-6 (321432 10^-5)^(n - 1)), 
    c[0] == 1, c[1] == 5}, c[n], n], n ∈ Integers] // First

(* c[n] -> *)
```

The first several values are

```
Table[Simplify[c[n] /. %], {n, 0, 8}]

(* {1, 5, 74999988159517/5000000000000, 244999948333156036527/5000000000000000000, 
    784999809145104350538564757/5000000000000000000000000, 
    2524999383279806241504389904195767/5000000000000000000000000000000, (4^(-4 - 3 n) 5^(-7 - 6 n) (10^(6 n) (1172409346315586312019869378750000 - 
   1088292064380910194582788537056291 Sqrt[2]) (1 - Sqrt[2])^n + 10^(6 n) (1 + Sqrt[2])^
   n (1172409346315586312019869378750000 + 1088292064380910194582788537056291 Sqrt[2]) + 
   1500000 (130809072583670204544034435447 240^n 13393^(1 + n) - 
   110652256667034006265872216 460811^(1 + n) - 756091031029961199112699840 (-1)^n 675131^
   (1 + n))))/89285790105620659634534766727097 
    8114998166092225878868708271269265029997/5000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
    26084994986029714868240982411237137250977319807/        
    5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
    83844987673045565789165365810827032895161630505820037/
    5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000} *)
```

or, numericized,

```
N[%, 15]

(* {1.00000000000000, 5.00000000000000, 14.9999976319034, 48.9999896666312, 
    156.999961829021, 504.999876655961, 1622.99963321845, 5216.99899720594, 
    16768.9975346091} *)
```

That these numbers are very close to being integers suggests that a more precise expression for `a` would yield integers directly.

*Edit: Computation of `b`*

Obtaining `b` from `c` is straightforward.  For convenience, define

```
fc[n_] := (4^(-4 - 3 n) 5^(-7 - 6 n) (10^(6 n) (1172409346315586312019869378750000 - 
   1088292064380910194582788537056291 Sqrt[2]) (1 - Sqrt[2])^n + 10^(6 n) (1 + Sqrt[2])^
   n (1172409346315586312019869378750000 + 1088292064380910194582788537056291 Sqrt[2]) + 
   1500000 (130809072583670204544034435447 240^n 13393^(1 + n) - 
   110652256667034006265872216 460811^(1 + n) - 756091031029961199112699840 (-1)^n 675131^
   (1 + n))))/89285790105620659634534766727097
```

Then

```
fb[n_] := Simplify[fc[n] + fc[n - 1] + 2 (794367 10^-7 (460811 10^-6)^n + 
    255972 10^-6 (-675131 10^-6)^n + 664591 10^-6 (321432 10^-5)^n)]
```

The two can be interleaved, as requested, by

```
fh[n_] := If[OddQ[n], fb[(n - 1)/2], fc[n/2]]
Table[fh[n], {n, 0, 11}] // N

(* {1., 4., 5., 10., 15., 34., 49., 108., 157., 348., 505., 1118.} *)

ListLogPlot[Table[fh[n], {n, 0, 30}] // N, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Another approach is to leave `a` undefined at first.

```
Simplify[RSolve[{c[n] == 2 c[n - 1] + c[n - 2] + 2 a[n], c[0] == 1, c[1] == 5},
   c[n], n], n ∈ Integers] // First;
Collect[% /. {K[1] -> k, K[2] -> k}, {a[0], a[1], _Sum}, Simplify[#, n ∈ Integers] &];
ReleaseHold[Hold[Evaluate[%]] /. {k, i1_, i2_} -> {i, i1 + 2, i2 + 2} /. 
    k -> k - 2 /. i -> k];
Simplify[% /. z1_ Sum[z2_, z3_] :> z1 Sum[z2, z3] + (z1 z2 /. k -> 0) + (z1 z2 /. k -> 1)]
    /. {k, 0, n + 1} -> {k, 2, n + 1}

(* {c[n] -> ((1 - Sqrt[2])^n - 2*Sqrt[2]*(1 - Sqrt[2])^n + (1 + Sqrt[2])^n + 
   2*Sqrt[2]*(1 + Sqrt[2])^n + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2])^n*
   Sum[((-1)^(2 - k)*(1 - Sqrt[2])^(-2 + k)*(-1 + Sqrt[2])*a[k])/Sqrt[2], {k, 2, 1 + n}]
   + 2*(1 - Sqrt[2])^n*Sum[((-1)^(2 - k)*(1 + Sqrt[2])^(-1 + k)*a[k])/
   Sqrt[2], {k, 2, 1 + n}])/2} *)
```

Results can be tested at each step of the simplification, in all cases yielding

```
Table[Simplify[c[n] /. % /. n -> i], {i, 0, 5}]

(* {1, 5, 11 + 2 a[2], 27 + 4 a[2] + 2 a[3], 65 + 10 a[2] + 4 a[3] + 2 a[4], 
   157 + 24 a[2] + 10 a[3] + 4 a[4] + 2 a[5]} *)
```

It is natural to ask whether the coefficients of `a` represent a known series, and they do.

```
2 FindSequenceFunction[Cases[Last@%, z_ a[_] -> z/2] // Reverse][n]

(* 2 Fibonacci[n, 2] *)
```

Thus, `c[n]` can be represented as

```
f[n_] := Simplify[1/2 ((1 - Sqrt[2])^n - 2 Sqrt[2] (1 - Sqrt[2])^n + (1 + Sqrt[2])^n + 
    2 Sqrt[2] (1 + Sqrt[2])^n)] + Plus @@ (2 Fibonacci[n + 1 - #, 2] a[#] & /@ Range[2, n])
```

One might hope that `a[n]`, rounded to the nearest integer, also represents a known series, but, `FindSequenceFunction` returns unevaluated.

```
Table[Round@a[n], {n, 0, 6}] // FindSequenceFunction

(* FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 7, 22, 71, 228, 733}] *)
```

**Second Addendum: `a`, `b`, and `c` in closed form**

[Vaclav Kotesovec](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29655/vaclav-kotesovec) made the very useful observation in a comment, that `a[n]`, rounded to integers, has the [recurrence relation](https://oeis.org/A030186),

```
a[n] == 3 a[n - 1] + a[n - 2] - a[n - 3]
```

It turns out that Mathematica can produce this result without difficulty, once it is realized from Kotesovec's comment that it is feasible to do so.  With `a[n]` as given above,

```
Table[FullSimplify[a[n]], {n, 0, 11}] // N // Round // FindLinearRecurrence
(* {3, 1, -1} *)
```

This can be solved to obtain `a` in closed form.

```
Clear[a]
a[n] /. First@RSolve[{a[n] == 3 a[n - 1] + a[n - 2] - a[n - 3], 
    a[0] == 1, a[1] == 2, a[2] == 7}, a[n], n]
(* Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n Root[-1 + 18 #1 - 74 #1^2 + 74 #1^3 &, 1] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n Root[-1 + 18 #1 - 74 #1^2 + 74 #1^3 &, 2] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n Root[-1 + 18 #1 - 74 #1^2 + 74 #1^3 &, 3] *)
```

Sample results are as expected,

```
Table[FullSimplify[%], {n, 0, 11}]
(* {1, 2, 7, 22, 71, 228, 733, 2356, 7573, 24342, 78243, 251498} *)
```

This exact result can be numericized to whatever precision is desired using `N`.  For `$MachinePrecision`,

```
%% // N
(* 0.255972 (-0.675131)^n + 0.0794367 0.460811^n + 0.664591 3.21432^n *)
```

which is the approximate expression for `a` shown in the question.  Now, all this would be of little interest, except that the same can be done for `b` and `c`!

```
Table[Simplify[fc[n]], {n, 0, 11}] // N // Round // FindLinearRecurrence
(* {3, 1, -1} *)
c[n] /. First@RSolve[{c[n] == 3 c[n - 1] + c[n - 2] - c[n - 3], 
    c[0] == 1, c[1] == 5, c[2] == 15}, c[n], n]
(* Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n Root[-1 - 25 #1 - 37 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 1] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n Root[-1 - 25 #1 - 37 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 2] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n Root[-1 - 25 #1 - 37 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 3] *)
Table[FullSimplify[%], {n, 0, 11}]
(* {1, 5, 15, 49, 157, 505, 1623, 5217, 16769, 53901, 173255, 556897} *)
%% // N
(* -0.428786 (-0.675131)^n - 0.0428314 0.460811^n + 1.47162 3.21432^n *)

Table[Simplify[fb[n]], {n, 0, 11}] // N // Round // FindLinearRecurrence
(* {3, 1, -1} *)
b[n] /. First@RSolve[{b[n] == 3 b[n - 1] + b[n - 2] - b[n - 3], 
    b[0] == 4, b[1] == 10, b[2] == 34}, b[n], n]
(* Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]^n Root[-2 + 90 #1 - 148 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 1] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^n Root[-2 + 90 #1 - 148 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 2] + 
   Root[1 - #1 - 3 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]^n Root[-2 + 90 #1 - 148 #1^2 + 37 #1^3 &, 3] *)
Table[FullSimplify[%], {n, 0, 11}]
(* {4, 10, 34, 108, 348, 1118, 3594, 11552, 37132, 119354, 383642, 1233148} *)
N // %%
(* 0.718273 (-0.675131)^n + 0.0230942 0.460811^n + 3.25863 3.21432^n *)
```

Thus, we have been able to provide in a straightforward manner both exact and `MachinePrecision` expressions for `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: bbgodfrey, Your answer is very helpful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If numerical values are desired:

```
a[n_] := .0794367 (.460811)^n + .255972 (-.675131)^
     n + .664591 (3.21432)^n;
b[j_] := c[j - 1] + c[j - 3] + 2 a[(j - 1)/2]
c[j_] := b[j - 1] + c[j - 2]
c[0] := 1
b[1] := 4
c[2] := 5
b[3] := 10
c[4] := 15
b[5] := 34.
```

Presentation:

```
fun[j_] := If[EvenQ[j], c[j], b[j]];
bcf[n_?OddQ] := 
 With[{r = {0 -> Red, 1 -> Blue}}, 
  Framed[TableForm[{Style[fun@#, Mod[#, 2] /. r], a@#} & /@ 
     Range[0, n], 
    TableHeadings -> {MapIndexed[
       Subscript[#1, 
         Style[ToString[#2[[1]] - 1], Mod[#2[[1]] - 1, 2] /. r]] &, 
       Flatten[Table[{Style["c", Red], Style["b", Blue]}, (n + 1)/
          2]]], {"value", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(n\)]\)"}}]]]
```

[image]

This does not scale well. I have not tried `FindSequenceFunction` etc. Others may wish to.

Apologies for any errors.

Comment: Sequence a(n) is https://oeis.org/A030186

Comment: Everybody has been quite helpful thus far! Thank you.

My original question can be formulated in the following manner: Can Mathematica solve (ie., find a "closed-form" formula for b[k]) for the following "piecewise" defined recurrence relation?

For integers k greater than or equal to 3, b[k] = b[k-1] + b[k-3] + 2*[.0794367(.460811)^((k-1)/2) + .255972(-.675131)^((k-1)/2) + .664591(3.21432)^((k-1)/2)], if k is odd; b[k] = b[k-1] + b[k-2], if k is even; b[0] = 1, b[1] = 4, b[2] = 5.


Sincerely, Richard M. Low

Comment: ubpdqn, Thank you for your reply. It is helping me to get to the final goal.

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec  Thank you for identifying the sequence `a[n]`.  Knowing its recurrence relation, I then was able to determine the recurrence relations with Mathematica for `b[n]` and `c[n]`.  Very helpful.